# JDBC: UserID as Primary Key , increasing in Java Code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

related to my last question: [Java SQL (JDBC) : how to move to the next column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337166/java-sql-jdbc-how-to-move-to-the-next-column/24337195#24337195)

I have one SQL Table including few columns , one of its columns is "UserID" which is PK and AI

what does the code do? :
1. get username , email and password from the user.
2. check if username or email already existed in the table.
3. if neither of the user nor the email are existed in the table I'll insert the username, email and password into the table.

however ,when I do the insert , I still need to insert a UserID

**since I can't run my code right now because I'm having problems with the Workbench MySQL, I just want to know if this code would work:**

```
        /* checks that last UserID in the Table */
        String command = "SELECT UserID FROM users";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);

        resultSet.last();
        id = resultSet.getInt("UserID") + 1;
```

and then when I use the **INSERT** query:

```
command = "INSERT users SET UserID = '" + id + "', UserName = '" + usr.toString()
                    + "',Email = '" + eml.toString()
                    + "',Password = '" + pwd.toString()
                    + "',Status = '0' ,Connected = '1';";
            statement.executeUpdate(command);
```

what do you think ?

THIS IS MY ENTIRE CLASS:

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

public class DB {

```
private String usr;
private String eml;
private String pwd;

private int id = 0;

private ResultSet resultSet;
private Statement statement;
private Connection connection;

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registered";
String jdbcUser = "...";
String jdbcPassword = "...";



int flag = 0;

public boolean checkSignUp(String usr, String eml, String pwd) {
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUser,
                jdbcPassword);
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        /* checks that last UserID in the Table */
        String command = "SELECT UserID FROM users";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);

        resultSet.last();
        id = resultSet.getInt("UserID") + 1;

        /* runs over the UserName column */
        command = "SELECT UserName FROM users WHERE UserName LIKE '"
                + usr.toString() + "';";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            if (usr.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("UserName"))) {
                System.out.println("UserName : " + usr.toString() + " is taken!");
                flag++;
            }
        }

        /* runs over the Email column */
        command = "SELECT Email FROM users WHERE UserName LIKE '"
                + usr.toString() + "';";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            if (eml.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Email"))) {
                System.out.println("Email : " + this.eml + " is taken!");
                flag +=2;
            }
        }

        /* if user\email exists or not */
        if (flag == 0) {

            System.out.println("Email : " + this.eml + " and UserName : "
                    + usr + " are AVAILABLE!");

            command = "INSERT users SET UserID = '" + id + "', UserName = '" + usr.toString()
                    + "',Email = '" + eml.toString()
                    + "',Password = '" + pwd.toString()
                    + "',Status = '0' ,Connected = '1';";
            statement.executeUpdate(command);
            return true;
        }
        else if (flag == 1) {
            //show error message
        }
        else if (flag == 2) {
            //show error message
        }
        else if (flag == 3) {

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Vendor error: " + e.getErrorCode());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    flag = 0;
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: "Select UserID from users order by UserID DESC LIMIT 1" will ensure that the largest UserID will be returned from the database, no need to query every UserID from database and get the largest one.

Comment: And you SQL is vulnerable to injection attack. Try using [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for update.

Comment: If it's an auto incrementing column, there should be no need to supply a value for the column. This could result in two competing threads from inserting the same value for the PK. Insert should be more in the format of "insert into [table] {(column{, column...})} values (...)"

Comment: @SayemAhmed after the **SELECT UserID from users ORDER BY UserID DESC LIMIT 1**
int id = resultSet.getInt("UserID") + 1; ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer so it should be ,... **INSERT INTO users (UserID,UserName,Email,..) VALUES (id,usr,eml,pwd,...)**

Comment: Yes, also check the prepared statements link provided by SayemAhmed

Comment: thanks, so far i'm having something like this **  String command = "SELECT UserID FROM users ORDER BY UserID DESC LIMIT 1;";
   statement = connection.prepareStatement(command);
   resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);**

or does not the executeQuery have to get arguments ?

Comment: PreparedStatement can't use the query methods that take the String query, simply use the no arguments methods, like "executeQuery"

Comment: thanks alot, i will try the code soon, i will post back for results

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with this code:

1. Your SELECT statement is selecting the entire users table. Probably not a good idea.
   If you are selecting from the user's table, you should probably have a "WHERE" or "LIMIT" somewhere.
2. It's unclear why you are adding 1 to the User ID (should probably add a comment).
3. Your INSERT statement seems to be slightly off syntactically (see the documentation... "SET" is used for "UPDATE", the INSERT statement looks more like "INSERT INTO...").
4. When creating a new user entry, you probably should not set the UserID explicitly. You should, instead, make that column auto-incrementing and then omit it in the INSERT statement, relying on the declaration of the table to cause the value to be automatically computed and set.
5. You are storing the password into the user's table, directly. If you are going to store the password, at the very least encrypt it (or, better yet, only store a salted hash of the password, nothing from which the password may be reconstructed). Even better, however, would be if you used OAuth, instead.
6. You need to escape your user-provided fields (as mentioned in some of the comments, prepared statements are the way to go for something like this).

Comment: i'm adding 1 to the UserID because when i insert a new row i want it to have a new UserID following the last UserID

Comment: @user3651124 with #4, when you declare the table, you can configure certain columns to be automatically set on insertion. For example, numeric values can "auto increment" -- that is, each insertion sets the value to one more than the value of the previously inserted record. Similarly, dates can be configured to initialize to the current time on an insert (they can also be configured to update again on an update, useful for tracking the last modified time).

Comment: @user3651124 with #5, basically storing passwords is not secure. Your best bet is to not store them or even ask your users for them. Instead, you should use OAuth, which allows users to sign-in with an identity provider of their choice (such as Google). You would then store an OAuth identifier rather than a password.

Comment: ok so according to #4, using
**INTO users (UserID,UserName,Email,..) VALUES (id,usr,eml,pwd,...)**
have to be without (UserID) .. (id) ..

Answer (score 1):

You can **alter** the table structure to auto increment the  UserID.

Else you can get the id value  as **SELECT max(UserID)+1 FROM users**

Since it is user credentials , rather than having as plain text it is advisable to encrypt them in the DB